# Creating counter to track of how many times a UITableViewcell has been selected for core data object

Tags: swift, core-data

Working on a application that keeps track of Users Selections from a tableview and the amount of times they selected that particular object with a limit maximum of 2 that if the cell is selected after the number 2 pops up it resets back to 0. I am also trying to limit the amount of the objects total to 30. I have 2 attributes in my core data entity related to this. A numberselected and deckCardCount the number selected is related to the objects directly and the deckCardCount is the total of those objects stored.

I wasn't sure if that was the best way to go about this as I also have thought in my head that maybe the limit be only within the view controllers that present the object. I need a little direction with this and some general help. Currently the counter that I created doesn't actually seem to work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var myDeckCards: DeckCards?
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards
    // check: is there already a DeckCards object for this Card and this Deck?
    let deckCardsSet = listed.cardselections
    println("The set of DeckCards for that Card is \(deckCardsSet.count)")
    for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections {
        let myDeckCard = eachDeckCard as! DeckCards
        if myDeckCard.cardsstored == passedDeckObject {
            // There is already a DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
            myDeckCards = eachDeckCard as? DeckCards
        }
    }
    if myDeckCards == nil {
        // There is no DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
        // So create one...
        myDeckCards = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DeckCards", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as? DeckCards
        myDeckCards!.cardsselected = listed
        myDeckCards!.cardsstored = passedDeckObject!
    }
    // your code to determine numberSelected here; I'll assume 2!
    var cardCount = 0
    func addCards() {
        if cardCount == 0 {
            cardCount++
        } else {
            if cardCount == 1 {
                cardCount++
            } else {
                if cardCount == 2 {
                cardCount == 0
            }
            }
        }
    }
    addCards()
    println(cardCount)

    myDeckCards!.numberSelected = cardCount
    managedObjectContext?.save(nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have an attribute that refers to a total? That does not make any sense. Keep one variable around that keeps track of the total.

Why are you using plurals to describe your managed objects? Why should a card have a class name `Cards` - refactor with singular!

Finally, your add function is absurdly verbose. This should be as simple as

```
timesSelected = timesSelected == 2 ? 0 : timesSelected + 1
```

Comment: Still new to programming in general so basically the variable will limit the user to only select 30 objects total and it will sum up the total of timesSelected to determine whether or not that limit has been reached?